# neo4j jdbc driver as a module on wildfly

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, wildfly, wildfly-11

I'm trying to install neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.3.1 as a module on Wildfly 11. I created the folders org/neo4j/driver/main and added the module.xml file as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="org.neo4j.driver">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.3.1.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="sun.jdk"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

I added the jar neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.3.1.jar in the same directory, but the module does not get deployed.

If I add the jar on the deployments folder it works, but I need the driver as a module.

Comment: Modules don't get deployed. Are you not able to add the driver?

Comment: Can't you just add the driver as a dependency so it get's bundled with your WAR?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins The only that i fount is addind the jar file to the wildfly's deployments folder, but the ideia is to install the driver as a module. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelHunger It would solve the problem but I have multiple war applications on the same Wildfly and on those apps  the user can select which datasource to be used based on a list of all datasources registered in the Wildfly Datasources, The Neo4j datasource will be just one more datasource pre configured on the wildfly instance that zero or more apps can use. Thanks

Comment: You might want to have a look at the class loading documentation. http://docs.wildfly.org/14/Developer_Guide.html#Class_Loading_in_WildFly